# Add C syntax highlighting to the nesc tag

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, syntax-highlighting

[nesC](http://nescc.sourceforge.net/) is an extension of C, aimed at embedded devices. Can we please set the default syntax highlighting to `lang-c` for the [nesc](/questions/tagged/nesc) tag?

*Also, if there is a more efficient way to get a tag associated with a language, I'd like to know. Based on some searching on meta, it seems feature-requests are the way to do it.*

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be cool if in the general case tag wiki creators could also specify the Prettify language hint(s) for the tag. I'm not sure how this is implemented currently, but I think people that create a tag are likely to know what syntax highlighting (if any) is likely to work for the language.

Comment: I like that idea. Might be worth posting a separate feature request / discussion.